# Setting a "publishing time" for Firebase database entries?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am planning an app that would allow users to create posts which shouldn't be readable by other users until the date/time that the creator of the post has selected.

Is this possible using the Firebase Realtime Database? How would I implement something like this?

I guess that simply implementing it in client code would not be secure, since authenticated users could still `GET` all posts manually, even the "not yet published" ones? Can I use database rules to do it, even though each post would have their individual publish date/time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible with Firebase. All you need to do is to add a flag for each post with the default boolean value of `false` and a `TIMESTAMP`. This means that by default, the post cannot be readable by other users. Then you need to use a listener on that `TIMESTAMP` filed to see when the current date/time is equal with the date/time that the creator of the post has selected. If it's equal then just set the value of the flag to `true`. This means that the post can be readable by other users. That's it!

You can achieve this also using security rules like this:

```
//Ensure that data being read is less than or equal with the current date/time.
".read": "data.child('timestamp').val() <= now"
```

Comment: I haven't read up on Firebase rules yet, but I take it that I would use the boolean flag as the basis of some rule, right? And the listener runs in the client webpage code?

Answer (score 1):

The only solution I can think of is creating an entirely new node `scheduledPosts` with it's own rules to only allow the creator to see/edit it before the publish date (if that's what you're aiming for).

```
{
  "users": {
     "uid_1": {
        "someData": "data",
        ...
     }
  },
  "scheduledPosts": {
    "pid_1": {
       "postData": "data",
       "uid": "uid_1",
       "publishDate": 1695840299,    // must be in milliseconds since epoch
       ...
    }
  }
}
```

And your `scheduledPosts`'s rules would look as follows:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "scheduledPosts": {
      "$post_id": {
        ".read": "root.child('scheduledPosts').child($post_id).child("publishDate").val() < now || root.child('scheduledPosts').child($post_id).child("uid") === auth.uid",
        ".write": "root.child('scheduledPosts').child($post_id).child("publishDate").val() < now || root.child('scheduledPosts').child($post_id).child("uid") === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use read rule, with combination of [now](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/api/rule/now.html)

The rule will look something like this:

```
".read": "(auth != null) && (data.child('publish_time').val() < now)"
```